# TCL read & split multiple stdin values

Tags: split, tcl, stdin

I would like to read and split multiple values entered via stdin.

For example:

```
set values [gets stdin]
```

==> there I read all the values entered by the user in 1 line separated by a space via stdin (for ex : `1 aa 55 do 54`) and put all these values in my variable `values`. Now I would like to have a way to split or read all these values separately to access each value.

Comment: yes indeed, with the separator : [split $values " "]. Thanks.

Comment: @user2669068 If the separator is a space, you don't need to specify it.

Comment: @Jerry: it depends. `split {foo  bar}` returns 2 elements, `split {foo  bar} { }` returns 3 elements.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Huh, `llength [split {foo bar} { }]` (Note the space in the second pair of braces) returns me 2, as does `llength [split {foo bar}]`.

Comment: @Jerry well, actually I wrote it as `{foo..bar}` (replace the `.` with a space), but something ate one of the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here as official answer:

```
split $values
```

or

```
split $values { }
```

What you need depends on what should happen with other whitespace (like tab) and successive whitespace (two spaces).

The second version splits inside successive spaces (`foo  bar` will yield an empty element between `foo` and `bar`), the other splits also on tabs, vertical tabs, newlines (you can't get any)..

Comment: If you can have multi-whitespace separators: `regexp -all -inline {\S+} $values`